# Bit converting arrays

Tags: c#

Well this is going to be a strange question but I want to know How can I do this, let me give you more details about my question:

lets say I have

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[8] { 16, 0, 16, 0, 16, 0, 16, 0 };
```

and let say memory looks like:

```
------------0---1---2---3---4---5---6---7-
byteArray---10--00--10--00--10--00--10--10
```

I want a method which converts this array to short array WITOUTH any loop because It's already there I mean its:

```
------------0---1---2---3---4---5---6---7-
byteArray---10--00--10--00--10--00--10--10
------------0-------1-------2-------3-----
shortArray--1000----1000----1000----1000--
```

I just want to see the byte array as short array they're just byte blocks I can make algorithm for it as with my knowledge but I have to use loops but I can feel It could be done without loops because It's already in memory and the length of byte array is power of 2

It is even able to be converted something into like this:

```
------------0-----------1-----------
intArray----10001000----10001000----
------------0-----------------------
longArray---1000100010001000--------
```

---

- I want to do this with pointers. But I get error:

---

```
//--Error   1   Cannot convert type 'byte[]' to 'short*'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the pointer to be a pointer to shorts:

```
short* shortArray = (short*)byteArray;
```

Of course, with great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: Note - depending on what you're trying to do, you may have to worry about endian-ness issues, too. But it's not clear that you need to from what you've written.

Comment: well thats unsafe code I think. and I don't really know why they call it unsafe. I have to look for it

Comment: A short-Pointer in C#? Yeah that doesn't call for trouble.

Comment: is there no other way to do it?

Comment: Nicholas Carey's way works, too, if you don't mind the overhead of copying the data.

Comment: Cannot convert type 'byte[]' to 'short*'

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have endian issues, this should do the trick:

```
byte[]  srcOctets = ReadOctets() ;
int     n         = srcOctets.Length / sizeof(short) ;
short[] tgtShorts = new short[ n ] ;

Buffer.BlockCopy( srcOctets, 0 , tgtShorts , 0 , n * sizeof(short) ) ;
```

You're basically moving the octets in the buffer underlying the source array instance to the buffer underlying the target array instance. The source and target arrays may be of any **primitive** type: Boolean, Char, SByte, Byte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Single, or Double.